# convert interger to decimal using databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a Integer value: 10000, which I want to databind it to the interface as 100.00.

```
android:text="@{BigDecimal(viewModel.transactionDetail.transaction.amount).toString()}"
```

Comment: use a custom [binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)

Comment: But 10000 and 100.00 are not equal. What is your purpose?

Comment: @Khemraj his purpose is to store `viewModel.transactionDetail.transaction.amount` in "cents" but display it in "dollars"

Answer (score -1):

> Data binding is not for implementing logics inside view, it is
>   provided to attach view to data models.

If you use controllers / handler, you can put your converting logic there. See [data binding documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/), you will always see Handlers in their examples.

#### Way 1

Using handler you can write your converting logic inside handler.

```
<variable
    name="handler"
    type="com.package.MainHandler"/>

android:text="@{handler.getAmountInDollar(transaction.amount)}"
```

In your Activity/Fragment

```
binding.setHandler(new Handler());
```

In Handler

```
public String getAmountInDollar(int amount) {
    return new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(amount);
}
```

#### Way 2

If you don't use presenter still, you can do this.

```
public class Transaction {
    private int amount;

    public String getAmountInDollar() {
        return new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(amount);
    }
}
```

Now you can do this

```
android:text="@{transaction.amountInDollar}"
```

That's the way you should do this.